# display html files based on the filename by searching it from the server

Tags: php, javascript

this is little complicated for me:
say my server has 1200 files for example:

`file:///D:/xampp/htdocs/bibek/address/WRTRThu-05-Jul-2012-14-02-14pm.html`
 `file:///D:/xampp/htdocs/bibek/address/WRTRThu-05-Jul-2012-13-02-23pm.html`
 `file:///D:/xampp/htdocs/bibek/address/BRTRThu-05-Jul-2012-13-05-35pm.html`
 `file:///D:/xampp/htdocs/bibek/address/BRTRThu-05-Jul-2012-12-06-52pm.html` etc.

as one can see each of them has a name: WRTR and BRTR and a day date and time.
i have to write a script with php mysql javascript(only the last the last resort), to let a user  to enter the date time day and the name (wrtr or brtr) and he will be able to view the corresponding files.
can anyone suggest how to proceed?

according to sugesstion and with the help of maxhud, i got this, hats off to you...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showFile(){
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var dday = document.getElementById("dday").value;
        var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
        var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
        var hour =document.getElementById("hour").value;
        var minute = document.getElementById("minute").value;
        var second = document.getElementById("second").value;
        var ofday = document.getElementById("ofday").value;
        var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
        var ofday=document.getElementById("ofday").value;
        window.location = "address/" + name + day + "-" + dday+ "-" + month + "-" + year + "-" +hour + "-" + minute + "-" + second + ofday + ".html";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

    Name: <input id="name" placeholder="accountname"/><br/>

    Date: <input id="dday" placeholder="01-31"/> - <input id="month" placeholder="month"/> - <input id="year" placeholder="year"/><br/><br/>


    Time: <input id="hour" placeholder="24hours"/> - <input id="minute" placeholder="minute"> - <input id="second" placeholder="second"/>
     of Day <input id="ofday" placeholder="am/pm"/>
     <br/><br/>
     Day: <input id="day"/>
     <br/><br/>

    <button onclick="showFile()">Take me to the file</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and the php script:
fileLocator2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <title>Ethernet database check</title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
    width:90%;
    max-height:auto;
    min-height:600px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:white;
    font-size:17px;
}
br{
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
#textleft
{
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
}
#textright
{
    float:right;
    margin-right:2em;
}
.inputcont{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    margin-left:0.1em;
    autofocus:autofocus;
}
a:link
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
title
{

    border-radius:5px;
    font-size:3em;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}

    .yellobutton
{
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-top:1%;
    float:right;
    margin-right:2%;
    width:10em;
    height:2.4em;
    border:1px solid blue;
    border:inset 1px solid black;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #fff;
    color:black;
    font-weight:bold;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
        <header style="height:4em;font-size:2em;"> Employee Access Only</header>
        <div style="margin:2em;padding:1em 1em 4em 1em;height:auto;border:1px solid #000;border-radius:5px;-moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px 2px #ddb;box-shadow:0 0 5px 2px #ddd;">
                <form method="POST" action="confirm.php">

            <div id="textleft">Path or folder:<br></div>
            <div id="textright"> <input id="path" name="path" placeholder="address no/"/>[?]</div><br/>

            <div id="textleft">Name of file:<br/></div>
            <div id="textright"> <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="filename"/><a href="#" title="WRTR &#13;BRTR">[?]</a></div><br/>

            <div id="textleft">Day:<br/></div>
            <div id="textright"> <input  id="day" name="day"/><a href="#" title="Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat">[?]</a></div>
            <br/>
            <div id="textleft">Date:</div>
            <div id="textright"><input  id="ddate" placeholder="01-31" name="ddate"/> - <input id="month" placeholder="month" name="month"/> - <input id="year" placeholder="2001-2011" name="year"/><a href="#" title="date:01-02-03..31 &#13;month:Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug&#13; year:2001...2011">[?]</a></div><br/>
            <div id="textleft">Time:<br/></div>
            <div id="textright"><input  id="time" name="time"/><a href="#" title="hours-mins-seconds &#13; 13-20-23">[?]</a></div></br>

        <input type="submit" class="yellobutton" id="submit" name="submit" value="show me"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    <footer style="font-size:1.4em ;margin-top:20%;">&copy;Bibek Agarwal Scripts</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

and confirm.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

    $pathfolder=trim($_POST['path']);
    $filename=trim($_POST['name']);
    $day=trim($_POST['day']);
    $ddate=trim($_POST['ddate']);
    $dmonth=trim($_POST['month']);
    $dyear=trim($_POST['year']);
    $time=trim($_POST['time']);
    /*echo 'path '.$pathfolder.'<br/>';
    echo 'filename '.$filename. '<br/>';
    echo 'day' . $day.'<br/>';
    echo 'time ' .$time. '<br/>';*/
     if((!empty($pathfolder)) && (!empty($filename)) && (!empty($day)) && (!empty($ddate)) && (!empty($dmonth)) && (!empty($dyear)) && (!empty($time)))
        {
            list($hour,$minute,$second)=explode("-",$time);


            echo 'hours '.$hour.'<br/>';
            echo 'minutes '.$minute.'<br/>';
            echo 'seconds '.$second.'<br/>';
            if(($hour>=12) && ($hour<=59))

                $flag="pm";

            if(($hour>=00) && ($hour<=11))
                  $flag="am";

                        $filesever=$pathfolder."/".$filename.$day."-".$ddate."-".$dmonth."-".$dyear."-".$hour."-".$minute."-".$second.$flag.".html";
                         header("Location:$filesever") ;
        }
        else 'Empty Inputs';

 }

?>
```

Comment: What have you looked into/tried? And are you quite sure you'd want PHP to call these files from the system hard drive (`file:///`)?

Comment: yes. they gave me a project, and theu saif to do it using html php .
no they didnot say from the harddrive they said from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showFile(){
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
        var dayom = document.getElementById("dayom").value;
        var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
        var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
        var day = document.getElementById("day").value;

        window.location = "address/" + name + day + "-" + dayom + "-" + month + "-" + year + "-" time + ".html";
    }
</script>
<style>
    input{
        display:block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    Name: <input id="name"/>
    Time: <input id="time"/>
    Day of the Month <input id="dayom"/>
    Month: <input id="month"/>
    Year: <input id="year"/>
    Day: <input id="day"/>
    <button onclick="showFile()">Take me to the file</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the user will be redirected to the html file

Comment: @RobW what?... he is not using localhost or anything like that at the moment so he won't be able to use php unless he does.

Comment: unless i do what. how do i emliminate the javascript?. ow just a minuite, its in my computer the address is file:///D:/xampp....
but its not the same everywhere....

Comment: @maxhud if he is not using localhost/domain then why would he ask for solution in php

Comment: @blackbee you don't... he doesn't know what he's talking about. if you want to use an alternative solution to this, you can use PHP, but it will involve installing software to use or using a web server.

Comment: @RabNawaz i don't know ask him. he's obviously not using localhost because if he was he wouldn't be using hard drive file system

Comment: @maxhud [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) *is* a distribution which is capable of running a web server.

Comment: i am using localhost, otherwise how do i test the codse? i think i should say once more, there are some 100 files like this with me,that i brought,back from  school and there are thousands on their server, in my computer is stored them in the folder name bibek in xampp, i dont know what is their's

Comment: okay my bad. put the updated code in my answer in a file called fileLocator.html in the folder 'bibek'

Comment: To be quite honest, I really don't understand what is so wrong about this solution. Sure, I would agree that fleshing it out into a full form and having a PHP script back it up would be better, just in case the user has JavaScript disabled, but honestly, sending this information to PHP to do the exact same thing is a waste of resources. Unless other processes need to run, using JS is the most logical approach.

Comment: type  localhost/bibek/fileLocator.html into your browser's url bar

Comment: you have a typo in your script tag. it says 'scrpit' and you aren't using the most recent code i posted

Comment: where do i put the script then? u can call ne nostalgic but i read a book where they wrote js codes like this.

Comment: just a minute , how do i enter the date and time? with dashes? as in the html file name?

Comment: hey excuse me, can u have to put a - sign after the day. in your code. i mean the address becomes D:/xampp/htdocs/bibek/address/WRTRThu05-Jul-2012-13-02-23pm.html. whereas there is a - sign after thu
how to do that?

Comment: ok. you know what you owe me more than a thanks. i thought i need 2 days to solve this. where and how did you learn this? its pathetic that this website doesnot allow me to vote as i don't have 15+reputations

Comment: hey, its not responding. nothing happens when i click take me to the file

Comment: try replacing your code with this my new code. you can thank me by clicking the little check next to my answer ;)

Comment: in your original post, you wrote `<script type="javascript">` when you should have written `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: and can you tell some good resources to learn these javascripts and php?

Comment: we aren't supposed to use comments for extended discussion. i recommend http://codecademy.com and tizag.com

Comment: i think you should learn some javascript and figure out how to do that. it would be a good learning experience and the solution you have does do what you need. you can make another question if you would like for people to provide an answer for, but we shouldn't add to this question any more.